# Image is 404 even though on the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nginx, capistrano, carrierwave

I've used the very good tutorial on railscast about carrierwave to upload pictures on the server, but even thought it is working perfectly in dev, in production it's not working anymore.

In my uploader I have this:

```
def store_dir
  "images/profile/#{model.id}"
end
```

the image is properly uploaded and is there but I get a 404 when I call the image...

Any ideas are wellcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If your using a hosting service such as Heroku you won't be able to just upload a file through carrierwave in production directly to your app and expect it to stay there (it may appear momentarily but not for long). You need to use an image hosting service such as aws, S3, etc. to integrate and "store" your files.

Also, the store_dir should probably look closer to something like this

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{Rails.env}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Not sure this is your issue but hope it helps!